# RenderBox was not laid out, Flutter Listview Builder not Displaying

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I'm New to this Framework, And I'm Unable to Display the ListViewBuilder Items. I'm  Getting this error in Console

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f28ee relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
class _ViewCartState extends State<ViewCart> {

  List<dynamic> cartData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    APIService apiService = new APIService();
    apiService.apiCall().then((value) async {
      setState(() {
        cartData = value.data.result.cartData;
        print(cartData);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    loadData();
    var veg;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: kHintColor, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text("Cart Page", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
      ),
      body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        // width: 500,   //if this Height I'm Not giving Then List not Displaying.
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                        child: Text("Your Cart Items",
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .headline6
                                .copyWith(
                                    color: Color(0xff616161),
                                    letterSpacing: 0.67)),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                        thickness: 1.0,
                      ),

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: cartData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                cartItemListTile(context, cartData, index),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                     ],
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      BottomBar(
                        text: "go to next page"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
```

This is my ListView builder Return Function

```
  ListTile cartItemListTile(
      BuildContext context, List<dynamic> cartData, int index) {
    int qty;
    return ListTile(
      title: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                cartData[index].itemimage.image,
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
              ),
              
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Please help me with that. I cant Set the Container Height Because I have lots of Fields out of that List Also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Listview.builder
Add these 2 lines ..

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: Thank You So much